# User control on a Form Running inside design mode(Bug)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

1. Dragged custom usercontrol onto form
2. The Usercontrol either causes Visual studio to crash or runs inside design mode

[Gif Of bug](https://gyazo.com/8f0fa6f079e8dbbedfa6fd7ea967d0f2)

So im pretty sure the user control on form isnt suppose to run while in design mode.

How the hell do i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode(v=vs.110).aspx

You can check DesignMode. If true means you are in design mode and should do nothing.

Comment: the DesignMode property is not always correct. I had to use this : DesignMode || LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime

Comment: where would i put this?

Comment: Also the User Control is dragged onto the form, not initiated by code.

Comment: I would say in that User Control, event Load. If DesignMode is false, then you can start to show animation. Otherwise do nothing.